# Error on SQL Server 2000 backup (.bak file) restored on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

When I try to restore a database in my new SQL Server 2012 instance I get this error :

> *Restore of database 'MyDb' failed.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)*
>
> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 8.00.2055. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 11.00.2218. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)*

Can you help me?

Comment: Is the error not self-explanatory?

Comment: Is it possible you selected the wrong backup file to restore? Clearly the backup was not taken on 2008.

Answer (score 17):

The database is a SQL Server **2000** database (version **8.00.2055**) - and you **cannot** directly update a SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2012.

You'll need to take an interim step first (restore it in SQL Server 2008, back it up from that server again).

See the [relevant MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx):

> *In SQL Server 2012, you can restore a user database from a database backup that was created by using SQL Server **2005 or a later version**.*

but SQL Server **2000** is **NOT** supported.

Comment: @JonSeigel: Thanks! I was looking for that article, but couldn't find it right then...

Comment: Also note that after restoring on SQL 2008 you might need to change compatibility level of the database to restore on later DBMS. But MS SQL 2005 database should be fine to restore even on SQL 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these below mansion reference would be help to you.

http://codeonaboat.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/sql-server-2008-creating-a-database-from-a-bak-file/

http://kb.eukhost.com/backup-and-restore-ms-sql-server-2008-database/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637958/how-do-i-import-a-bak-file-into-microsoft-sql-server-2012

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation?  Link-only answers are discouraged by the site's standards written in the [FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).